# Python Loop with same key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this :

```
aa =     [
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.018406, 'date': u'2015-12-03', 'calc': -0.018406},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.043895, 'date': u'2015-12-04', 'calc': -0.043895},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.025996, 'date': u'2015-12-05', 'calc': -0.025996},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.034537, 'date': u'2015-12-06', 'calc': -0.034537},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.053107, 'date': u'2015-12-07', 'calc': -0.053107},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.060436, 'date': u'2015-12-08', 'calc': -0.060436},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253004, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.047265, 'date': u'2015-12-09', 'calc': -0.047265},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.075509, 'date': u'2015-12-03', 'calc': -0.075509},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.122235, 'date': u'2015-12-04', 'calc': -0.122235},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.096103, 'date': u'2015-12-05', 'calc': -0.096103},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.116113, 'date': u'2015-12-06', 'calc': -0.116113},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.112743, 'date': u'2015-12-07', 'calc': -0.112743},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.125755, 'date': u'2015-12-08', 'calc': -0.125755},
     {'id_o': 14285, 'id': 253007, 'value1': '0', 'value2': 0.126911, 'date': u'2015-12-09', 'calc': -0.126911}
    ]
```

How i can do a loop by dict with same id?

I need to compare value1 value2 and calc per day by ID

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I think I can ... There is a easy way to transform it?

Comment: Nah sorry, you can keep it this way. I misunderstood it. Please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` for an easy transformation to a dict: `{id: [dict]}`:

```
from itertools import groupby
# from operator import itemgetter

key = lambda d: d['id']
# key = itemgetter('id')  
# mostly a matter of taste, but itemgetter is more performant in some contexts

id_dicts = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(aa, key=key), key=key)}
```

Now, you can loop over ids:

```
for id in id_dicts:
    # do stuff
    for d in id_dicts[id]:
        # do stuff with d['value1'], d['value2'], etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it !

Comment: If you wanted, you could also do `from operator import itemgetter` and use `key = itemgetter('id')`

Comment: @JonClements True. I don't think that it's really relevant for the level of the question, but updated my answer anyway.